# Is this proof of the formula of the covariance of linearly transformed random variables correct?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I want to prove that $cov(AX+a,BY+b) = Acov(X,Y)B^t$ for any matrices $A,B$ and vectors $a,b$ if $X$ and $Y$ are normal distributed vectors, where $m$ is the mean of $X$ and $n$ the mean of $Y$

Is this proof correct? I am basically only using the linearity of the expectation $E$. It seems that I didn't even use properties of the normal distribution, so this should be true for any distributions with the given properties, right?

$$\begin{align*} cov(AX+a,BY+b) &= E[(AX+a - Am-a)(BY+b-Bn-b)^t] \\
&= E[(AX- Am)(BY-Bn)^t]\\
&= E[AXY^tB^t]-E[AXn^tB^t]-E[AmY^tB^t]+E[Amn^tB^t]\\
&= A\cdot E[XY^t]B^t-A\cdot E[X]n^tB^t-Am\cdot E[Y^t]B^t+Amn^tB^t\\
&=A(E[XY^t]-E[X]n^t-mE[Y^t]+mn^t)B^t\\
&=A(E[(X-m)(Y-n)^t]B^t\\
&=Acov(X,Y)B^t
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct, and you're right it's true for any distribution.